# Reading PDF text as String in R

Tags: r, nlp

```
install.packages("pdftools")

library("pdftools")

pdf.file <- "https://eparlib.nic.in/bitstream/123456789/809853/1/pms_16_17_07-02-2019_eng.pdf"

setwd("D:/Assignment 1/")

download.file(pdf.file, destfile = "speech1.pdf", mode = "wb")

pdf.text <- pdftools::pdf_text("speech1.pdf")

cat(pdf.text[[2]])

typeof(pdf.text)
```

I want to read the text as strings instead of characters. I was not able to find the ways to read it as strings instead it always ended up being read as characters.

Comment: Not sure what's the issue. In R a string (a single character, a word, a sentence, ...) is of type `character`. There is no `string` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of *pdftools::pdf_text* is not a list, but a simple character:

```
> library(pdftools)
> x <- pdf_text("bla.pdf")
> typeof(x)
[1] "character"
```

You thus cannot use the index operator `[[i]]` on the return value. If you want to extract individual cahracters, you must use *substr*:

```
> substr(x, 3, 3)
[1] "l"
```

Comment: Of course could one use `[[`. `pdf_text` "returns a character vector of equal length to the number of pages in the PDF file". Hence `x[[2]]` will return the text for the second page

Comment: Ah, my example only had one page.